# App not supported by HTC explorer and samsung galaxy ace

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am not able to find my app from google play store for HTC explorer and sansung galaxy ace devices, I am supporting small screens as well for the app, still not able to find it on play store

My manifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.demo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
        android:protectionLevel="normal" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" > 
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA">
    </uses-permission>

    <supports-screens android:largeScreens="false" android:smallScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" android:normalScreens="true" />

    <application 
        android:icon="@drawable/appicon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:debuggable="true">
        <service
            android:exported="true"
            android:name=".account.AuthenticationService" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
                android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name="abc.com.Screen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" >
                </action>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" >
                </category>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Please tell me if I am doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. `botteaap` fix worked.

Add this to manifest

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
```

and all worked fine.

`it means that the application prefers to use the feature if present on the device, but that it is designed to function without the specified feature`,

Comment: If my fix works, shouldn't my answer be accepted instead of this one?

Answer (score 1):

You likely need to declare camera autofocus as an optional feature (since you are requiring the camera based on the CAMERA permission). I haven't checked but it could be that those cheaper phones do not support auto focus.

For reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html and
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html (set `android:required` to false)

Answer (score 0):

There are several steps(pretty long steps) that can help you to verify which devices exactly can download and run your application:

1. Change or remove any permission in your manifest.
2. Build application with your release key.
3. Upload new `.apk` file to google play dev. console and activate it.
4. DO NOT PUBLISH it and switch to product details tab.
5. Check supported devices list via `show devices` link in `Supported Devices` section right under countries list. Here you can find list of all "google-known" android devices that can run your application with current permissions.

This way is pretty long, but this could help you.